# Storing https data in angularJS

Tags: json, angularjs, rest

I'm making a web app and learning AngularJS at the same time but am having trouble storing data that will be needed throughout the entire app. In one of my controllers, I have a POST call that returns a JSON object containing data that I need in separate parts of my app and I don't know how to store the entire JSON object so that I can access it later on. How can I store the JSON object so that I can access it later in a different controller? Should I even bother doing this or should I just make another POST request later on to get the data I need at that time (is it expensive to make POST/GET requests)?

Answer (score 0):

You certainly don't want to keep making POST request for the same data (assuming it hasn't changed).

You could store it on $rootScope, pass the $rootScope to whatever controller needs access to the data and access via:

```
 var whatever = $rootScope.yourObject;
```

Example:

```
  //Assuming a controller makes the POSt request (not in app.run etc)
 function yourController($rootScope, $http) {

       $http.post("desired/url", { params: "foo-bar"}).then(function(response){
            //Check for errorz etc.
            $rootScope.yourObject = response.data; //Assign to rootscope
       });

 }


 function someOtherController($rootScope){
      //Fetch the item from $rootScope, assuming the POST request was 
      // already made.
      var valueFromPreviousRequest = $rootScope.yourObject;
 }
```

Comment: `$rootScope` shouldn't be used for this purpose, a simple service would be a far better answer. `$http` also allows to set `cache:true`

Comment: Agree, it's the 'evil globals' thing. However, I wouldn't create a Service solely to store data, likewise I wouldn't put a function on $rootScope - I think there are a couple of use-cases where rootScope is viable to store data.

Comment: So yeah, 9/10 times I would agree with you - I use services as a rule of thumb, although without the context of the data given (is it meant to be available throughout the entire app?) I wouldn't go as far as to say rootScope shouldn't be used for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

The optimal approach would be to use custom service layer for data fetching and avoid `$http` in controller. In this case it's very easy to add caching mechanism.

For example, simple service:

```
app.factory('stats', function($q, $http) {

    // Hold cache in local variable
    var cache = null;        

    return {
        load: function() {
            return cache ? $q.when(cache) : $http.get(statsUrl).then(function(response) {
                cache = response.data;
                return data;
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Then you could use this service like this in controller:

```
app.controller('someController', function(stats) {
    stats.load().then(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

Note, how service `load` method returns [promise object](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) in both cases: when cache is already available and when no data has been loaded yet (first call).